# Is it impossible to tell a lobster's age?

Tags: biology, zoology

[image: Stephen Fry - QI] <sup>[Source](http://www.qi.com/)</sup>

[Stephen Fry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Fry) said in the [QI](http://www.qi.com/) episode "[I-Spy](http://www.comedy.co.uk/guide/tv/qi/episodes/9/1/)":

> "***You can't tell the age of a lobster*** "

([watch video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7ci8GB0nEM#t=1162s))

From the [American Lobster FAQ](http://www.parl.ns.ca/lobster/faq.htm):

> **There is no foolproof way to determine a lobster’s age**.
>   
>   One can only make an educated guess by
>   looking at the lobster’s size.

From [Visit Maine](http://www.visitmaine.net/lobsters.htm):

> **No one has yet found a way to determine the exact age of a lobster**
>   because it sheds its shell so often.
>
> A lobster's age is approximately his weight [*in pounds* ] multiplied by 4, plus 3 years.

(add to that, Lobsters might be able to [live forever](http://clubs.calvin.edu/chimes/article.php?id=6006), as mentioned by Sandi Toksvig in the QI episode)

---

**My Question:**

- Is body
  size/weight the only biological indicator we can use to make an
  "*educated guess* " about a lobster's age?

Comment: I cut them open, look for rings, and if I don't find any, I eat them.  :)

Comment: "his weight multiplied by 4, plus 3 years" -- weight in what units?

Comment: @Flimzy, apparently pounds. In context, that is the unit the rest of the page uses for weight.

Comment: @Odd - thanks for clarifying the "unit". But I'm not so happy with your title change. Now it reads more like a random question, with the claim being implied indirectly. If it's okay I'll change it back to something more direct.

Comment: @Oliver, sorry you didn't like the change. I was just trying to make it a question (like CHAOS do on many of the SE sites). I'm happy with the current one.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In many species, small granules of waste material - called "[lipofuscin](http://wwwchem.csustan.edu/chem4400/SJBR/lipofus.htm)" - build up in the body over time. As it turns out, this can be used to measure the [metabolic age](http://www.quickmedical.com/health_information/weight_management/metabolic_age.html) of lobsters, and to give a good estimate of their chronological age.

[Wahle, Tully & O'Donovan (1996)](http://www.int-res.com/abstracts/meps/v138/p117-123/) found a strong correlation between lipofuscin area (corrected for carapace size) and lobster age in American lobsters (*Homarus americanus*). Metabolic age is not a precise measure of chronological age - it is affected by several other factors, including temperature, and this study controlled temperature, so they caution about using it to measure age in natural populations.

[Sheehy et. al. (1996)](http://www.int-res.com/abstracts/meps/v143/p99-111/) released 3-month old European lobsters (*Homarus gammarus*) (after tagging them) into the wild and then recaptured them 5.4-9.6 years later. Extrapolating from their results led them to suggest that lipofuscin concentration could age 43% of lobsters to within 1yr and 95% to within 3.5yrs - not brilliant but better than carapace length, which other studies have found only age 3% to within 1yr and 95% to within 82(!) years (*what was that about lobster immortality, again?*).

[Maxwell et. al. (2007)](http://www.biolbull.org/content/213/1/55.full) conclude:

> We show that neurolipofuscin concentration, measured histologically in the central nervous system of laboratory-reared Caribbean spiny lobsters, *Panulirus argus*, is correlated with the chronological age of both males and females. These results suggest that the neurolipofuscin technique holds great promise for use in estimating age of wild-caught spiny lobsters.

[Sheehy et. al. (2011)](http://www.nrcresearchpress.com/doi/abs/10.1139/f98-016) described lipofuscin accumulation as "remarkably constant" at 0.31% (by volume) per year in wild western rock lobsters (*Panulirus cygnus*).

Of course, using a fluorescence microscope to measure the concentration of micrometre-sized granules in a lobster's eyestalk is a bit of effort to go to to find out how long it took your dinner to grow.

Answer (score 4):

For any creature, there is only one way to know how old it is: record its time of birth.

However, there are plenty of proxy measurements that are strongly correlated to age - [the wear of the teeth of a horse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horse_teeth#Estimating_age_using_the_teeth), [whether an insect is still a larvae](http://insects.about.com/od/forensicentomology/a/CSItimeofdeath.htm), etc. They may not give perfect values, but provide a reasonable estimate.

For many animals, size is a reasonable proxy for age (e.g. [corn snake length](http://www.ehow.com/how_8411301_determine-corn-snakes-age-length.html)). In such cases, maybe further research could develop other techniques - blood chemistry, bone density, etc., but why bother searching hard for it when you already have a reasonable technique?

So, why should we find it odd that - given you can get a reasonable age estimate for a lobster age by size - no-one has developed another technique?

Is it the only technique? Marine biologist and lobster expert [Jell Atema](http://www.bu.edu/research/spotlight/magazine/06/adapt/atema.html) is quoted as confirming this:

> KRULWICH: [...] with lobsters, the bigger you are, the older you are. That's how you age a lobster, by size.
>
> Prof. ATEMA: That's right. Yeah.
>
> [...]
>
> Prof. ATEMA: There's absolutely no indication that this lobster is showing signs of old age.
>
> KRULWICH: In fact, lobsters in general show no discernable signs of aging. They don't lose appetite, sex drive, energy, no change in metabolism.
>
> Prof. ATEMA: Something we could all be jealous of.

Source: [NPR](http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=16349118)

*Having seen Jivlain's answer, posted while I wrote this, I am not so sure Atem is correct here.*

Comment: `For many animals, size is a reasonable proxy for age` - don't most animals stop growing once they reach "adulthood"? Although I have heard the claim that for some marine animals there is no theoretical maximum size (as long as they have enough to eat they will keep getting bigger).