# Do spiders never stop growing during their lifetimes?

Tags: biology, arachnology

In the a recent *Doctor Who* episode, *[Arachnids in the UK](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7689200/)*, it is claimed that spiders never stop growing.

Is this true?

Comment: Is there a Dr Who tag? Should there be?

Comment: I'm under the belief that insects as well as nearly all creatures with exoskeletons never stop growing. In fact, I'm under the impression that is the reason many of them die. Their organs cannot manage their size any longer. Probably a better question for https://biology.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @matt_black: No. We don't get many questions ABOUT the show, and we don't tag claimants.

Comment: Related: [Lobsters growing indefinitely](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8520/under-the-right-circumstances-can-lobsters-live-indefinitely)

Comment: I don't think that a statement made in fiction should be considered notable.

Comment: @PaulJohnson The trouble with that is there are many apparently factual statements about the real world made in fiction and people do believe them. We should clearly ignore statements about the fictional world (so skeptical analysis of Dalek biology is clearly off topic).

Comment: @Oddthinking I was being somewhat ironic when I wrote that! ;-)

Comment: @matt_black Its an interesting question. I'll take it to meta.

Answer (score 8):

Tailless whip spiders (aka cave spiders or tailless whip scorpions) continue growing throughout their life:

> No terminal molt takes place and so these animals grow all their life, but obviously the intervals between molts get longer in time. Both sexes have extremely elongated pedipalps, but the male's pedipalps are longer still.
>   <sub>[Euphrynichus bacillifer](http://www.panarthropoda.de/sub/haltung/geisselspinnen/familien/euphrynichusbacilliferen.php)</sub>

> They molt once or twice a year until they reach maturity. Tailless whip scorpions continue molting and growing throughout their adult lives.
>   <sub>[*Phrynichus jayakari* Whip Spider](https://web.archive.org/web/20181029004034/http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:92kLAAJU2qkJ:cincinnatizoo.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Whip-Spider-Amblypygid.pdf+&cd=16&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)</sub>

> The order Amblypygi includes ca. 150 species and 17 genera within five families. Amblypygids are dorsoventrally flattened chelicerates with prominent raptorial pedipalps and chelate chelicerae. They are also the only arachnid order that lack an ultimate (= terminal) molt (Weygoldt 2002). The anteriormost legs of amblypygids are antenniform, being extremely long and whip-like (hence their common name, Whip Spiders)
>   <sub>[Ecology and natural history of the tree-inhabiting social amblypygid Heterophrynus batesii](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Kenneth_Chapin/publication/224608256_Ecology_and_Natural_History_of_the_Tree-inhabiting_Social_Amblypygid_Heterophrynus_Batesii_Butler_1873_Amblypygi_Phrynidae_in_Eastern_Amazonian_Ecuador/links/0922b4f905de5e7a48000000/Ecology-and-Natural-History-of-the-Tree-inhabiting-Social-Amblypygid-Heterophrynus-Batesii-Butler-1873-Amblypygi-Phrynidae-in-Eastern-Amazonian-Ecuador.pdf)</sub>

Comment: This answer could need a picture. *enters "Tailless whip spider" into image search*. This answer does definitely not need a picture.

Comment: @philipp They're harmless, you know. Cute, even.

Comment: Tailless whip spiders are large but they aren't ugly. I'd like to pet one some day.

Comment: @JohnDvorak you and I are on two different sides of the spectrum on that opinion. Petting them didn't quite make my bucket list.